# Maven module versioning - best practice

Tags: maven, versioning, multi-module

If I have a multi-module project, let's simplify it to:

  my project
- module a
- module b

where module b depends on module a.

If I make changes in module b, and update its version, should I also increase the version of module a, even if this module has not been changed?

Thank you,
Roxana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer: it depends.

If your modules are just inalienable parts of a big complex project then it makes sense to have the same version in every project.

On the contrary, if your modules are low coupled (for example `A` is web service and `B` is Android client for `A`) then you may have different versions in each.